# Function Values Surrounding Stationary Points

Tags: differentiation, mathematics, calculus, approximations

Taylor, in his widely read book "Classical Mechanics," writes on page 218 that

> When $df/dx = 0$ at a point $x_0$, but we don't know which of the 3 possibilities obtains, we say that $x_0$ is a **stationary point** of the function $f(x)$, since an infinitesimal displacement of $x$ from $x_0$ leaves the function unchanged (because the slope is $0$).

Is this technically true?  I thought the secant lines drawn from $x$ to $x_0$ only always approach $0$ as $\Delta x$ approaches $0$. Therefore, $f(x_0 + dx)$ might yield a different value from that of $f(x_0)$, even if the two values are very, very close.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The key word in *infinitesimal*,  which is shorthand for  "in the limit as $dx\to 0$".

Answer (score 2):

This can be interpreted in terms of the Taylor series around $x_0$. Since $f'(x_0)=0$,

$$ f(x_0+\delta x) = f(x_0) + \mathcal{O}(\delta x^2)$$

Here $\mathcal{O}(\delta x^2)$ contains powers of 2 and above in $\delta x$, which can be ignored at first-order approximation.

Answer (score 2):

The word "infinitesimal" is doing a lot of heavy lifting in that phrase.

Indeed, as you point out, the function values, although they might be very similar, are *not* the same at $f(x_0)$ and $f(x_0 + \delta x)$.

But, as pointed out in the [recent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/697065/8563), the difference between the two values scales quadratically, instead of linearly, when the derivative is zero:
$$
f(x_0+\delta x) - f(x_0) = f'(x) \, \delta x + \mathcal O(\delta x^2) = \mathcal O(\delta x^2).
$$

In essence, saying that $\delta x$ is "infinitesimal" amounts to saying "we neglect anything that scales with $\delta x$ to any power higher than linear". Thus, the function is not "truly" stationary $-$ it is stationary to linear order in the displacement. Which is fine!

Answer (score 1):

This statement can be made true under some number systems, but under the reals it doesn’t actually make sense. To see this, consider the Taylor expansion: $$f(x+\Delta x)=f(x)+f’(x)\Delta x+f’’(x)\Delta x^2 +…$$ Now, since $x$ is a stationary point, $f’(x)=0$ and therefore for infinitesimal $dx$ we have $f(x+dx)=f(x)+f’’(x)dx^2+…$ which “leaves the function unchanged” if $f’’(x)dx^2+…=0$. So, if the author had said “to first order” then it would have immediately been clear and correct.

Now, with reals you can’t actually speak of infinitesimal displacements to begin with so you have to interpret the above as referring to a finite $\Delta x$ and taking the limit as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$. So in that sense the statement is sloppy so it isn’t exactly right, but it is not exactly wrong either.

However, with hyperreals $f’’(x)dx^2+…\ne 0$, so under the hyperreals the statement is simply false. It could be made true if $f$ were defined as a real-valued function taking a hyperreal argument, but with that definition it would be true for non-stationary functions also.

With smooth infinitesimal analysis the statement is true without modification and not even sloppy since in that framework infinitesimals are nilsquare meaning that they have the property $dx\ne 0$ and $dx^2=0$. This implies that $f’’(x)dx^2+…=0$.

I think probably the best interpretation is that the author was referring to real numbers and the statement is sloppy, but not exactly wrong. Physicists are frequently sloppy with their math, with no harm.